# Automate a MySQL Installation

Tags: automation

I want to automate a specific MySQL Installation.

I install MySQL, Workbench and a ODBC tool with the same configuration (in the installation) on many computers, and I want to create a .exe which installs all software with a defined configuration.

A user who wanted to install this software then just has to execute the .exe and has nothing to configure (in the installation)

Comment: I try to use MySQLInstallerConsole, but it's a little bit complicated and the MySQL documentation is not exhaustive. I need to install softwares and configure them also

Answer (score 0):

I find this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html

But I don't find the correct syntax to install MySQL Server and how to define the port, the root password, the MySQL service name. There is no indication on the command line options...